# Number of words with using 2 letters independent to cycle shift

Tags: combinatorics

How do I get the number of words with exactly $n$ letters 'a' and $m$ letters 'b' such that if I cycle shift the letters to the right $k$ times, the word would not change.

For example, let $n = m = 3$, and $k = 4$. All possible words are: "ababab" and "bababa". To demonstrate the shifting, let's show that word "abbbaa" is incorrect: $abbbaa \to aabbba \to  aaabbb \to baaabb \to bbaaab$.

Comment: Hint: The answer depends on $\gcd(m+n,k)$.

Comment: Thank you! I got: $C_d^{\frac{md}{m+n}}$, where $d=gcd(m+n, k)$.